# EF Core can't connect to Oracle ('licensekey' is an invalid connection string attribute), but Dapper can

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

We have a project that was recently migrated from .NET Core 3 to .NET 6. It only had Dapper at first but now it also has EF Core. They both use the same connection string. Dapper's connection works normally but EF Core throws error

```
 OracleCompositeMemberTranslator.CreateDbConnection() :  System.ArgumentException: 'licensekey' is an invalid connection string attribute
```

Thing is we use the *licensekey* argument in all of our other connection strings (both dapper and EF Core) and they work fine. I tried removing it here but that crashes both dapper and EF Core. I'm guessing the issue might be with .NET 6 but I haven't found any documentation about it. Any ideas?

Comment: How have you configured your EF context?

Comment: Your license may be for only one connection.  When you are trying simultaneously on two machines you exceed the license.  Are you working on same machine?

Comment: @DavidG : Do not always believe the error message.  The error is coming from the driver.  Oracle has an history of different vendors drivers not always working properly.  So the OP should make sure they are using the same driver in both cases.  Oracle also has a number of version of releases and if the driver does not match the version of database you can have issues.  It is always best with Oracle to use the Oracle driver and not a 3rd party driver.

Comment: @jdweng Because you didn't suggest it was a driver issue, you said it was a bad licence key. I might give an answer if OP gives an update on how they configured EF. Until then, the question is impossible to answer.

Comment: @DavidG Not sure this is what you're asking but
``` services.AddDbContext<POADbContext>(x =>
                x.UseOracle(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LBANK"))
            );
```

Comment: @jdweng I have both connections from the same process running on one machine

Comment: You are using a translator : OracleCompositeMemberTranslator.  It looks like it may be the translator that is the issue.  Talk to Oracle. Ask if there are any issue using the translator with Core and especially the license issue.

Comment: @jdweng but shouldn't such issue be a problem for both Dapper and EF Core?

Comment: I can't tell if Dapper is using the translator, a different version of the translator, or different options in the translator.  All I can see is the exception is being generated in the translator.

Comment: @jdweng This is what dapper is using:
`services.AddTransient<IPOADBProvider>(x => new POADBProvider(new OracleConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LBANK"))));`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with using incorrect Nuget for EF Core. I needed *Devart.Data.Oracle.EFCore*